# Hide errors and warnings from console

Tags: javascript, jquery

In PHP and other languages there are ways to suppress error/warning messages.

Is there a way in javascript or jquery to prevent errors and warnings from being written to the console log?

Comment: Yea, disable those messages in the console itself (There should be some filter options). However, why would you want to hide errors? That sounds dodgy...

Comment: How about `console.clear();` ?

Comment: I hid all the errors and warnings from the console in my sites/apps by fixing the code.

Comment: I don't know if it was Darren's intention, but i went in a case where i needed to check if a resource was available and, if not, the code generated an error on the console.
I didn't tested `try { } catch(e) { }` to see if it suppress the console error. I'll test it.

Comment: console.clear(); is good option to hide the console error because some time on running site we don't want to show error so we hide them in PHP.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You **can handle errors to some extent but if error is not handled by you then it goes to browser** and you can not stop *browser* showing it. You can write code in such a way that you get minimum error and using `try-catch` where possible to handle the exceptions.

```
try
{
    //statements suspected to throw exception.
}
catch(e)
{
}
```

Comment: There must be a way to create a middleware (kindof) functionality that does error/exception handling for you. If someone finds (has found one) please reply.

Answer (score 26):

A dirty way to hide all Javascript console warnings is by overriding the console object's `warn` method:

```
console.warn = () => {};
```

Obviously, it also works with other console methods

Comment: this is what I was looking for, works in node.js as well

Answer (score 3):

After doing some research and development for this problem, I came across this solution which will hide warnings/Errors/Logs as per your choice.

```
(function () {
    var origOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function () {        
        console.warn = function () { };
        window['console']['warn'] = function () { }; // For confirmation again
        this.addEventListener('load', function () {                        
            console.warn('Something bad happened.');
            window['console']['warn'] = function () { };
        });        
    };
})();
```

Add this code before JQuery plugin (e.g /../jquery.min.js) even as this is JavaScript code that does not require JQuery. Because some warnings are in JQuery itself.

Comment: Not really sure why you would need all that extra baggage if `console.warn = () => {};` has the same effect. For instance `console.warn` and `window['console']['warn']` refer to the same function, so they are overridden twice in this code.

Answer (score 2):

Best to user 
console.clear();
in 90% of your cases it will be resolved

Comment: Clearing the console does not help in most situations - usually if you're wanting to hide certain types of console entries, it's because you are looking for something in the console of another type - probably console.log() output and the console is cluttered with error output.

Answer (score 1):

This is browser based functionality, you may install any addon for browser then you can hide errors/ warnings

I went to `about:config` for Firefox and turned `javascript.options.strict` to false and the warnings went away. But I feel like this is not a solution.

```
howtocreate.co.uk/strictJSFirefox.html
```

Comment: `javascript.options.strict` no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

you just simply add some chunk of code into the script it will works.!
Chrome:

```
console._commandLineAPI.clear();
```

Safari:

```
console._inspectorCommandLineAPI.clear();
```

You can create your own variable, which works in both:

```
if (typeof console._commandLineAPI !== 'undefined') {
    console.API = console._commandLineAPI;
} else if (typeof console._inspectorCommandLineAPI !== 'undefined') {
    console.API = console._inspectorCommandLineAPI;
} else if (typeof console.clear !== 'undefined') {
    console.API = console;
}
```

After that, you can simply use

```
console.API.clear().
```

Answer (score -3):

I usually just go to the implementation of the function that includes that particular console.log warning and comment it out.

Comment: In your own code this is obviously the simplest solution. However, when we talk about 3rd party libraries, where this problem usually occurs, changing the library code will prevent you from updating the library. Also it doesn't work if you share dependencies with your team through a list of requirements (which is the de-facto standard nowadays).