# Hide url of video

Tags: jquery, html, video

I have a page which dynamically embeds a video within an `iframe`. The link to the video is to an external source as the video is stored externally (e.g. YouTube say). The URL of the link is not directly visible to the user and the url is loaded from my database using jQuery.

However, whenever there is a firewall the video does not load, which is fine. But the `iframe` shows the complete URL to the link of the embedded video. Something like this:

> The web page at https://******** might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

I do not want this message to appear. Is there a way to do it?

P.S. This is more of a problem in chrome. Does not happen in IE

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21549176/4248328   and   https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catch error if iframe src fails to load . Error :-"Refused to display 'http://www.google.co.in/' in a frame.."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273042/catch-error-if-iframe-src-fails-to-load-error-refused-to-display-http-ww)