# Message from server in console of browser Angular 5

Tags: node.js, angular, google-chrome

I have a little question in Angular5 when I try to connect in my account and If I have an error like wrong password in browser console, also I have the message about me server(500) and I don't want dispaly this message in the console of browser. How can I desactive this message in console's browser.

```
err => {
   if( err instanceof HttpErrorResponse ) {
      if (err.status === 401) {
       this._router.navigate(['/login'])
     }
   }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549139/hide-errors-and-warnings-from-console

Answer (score 0):

If error comes from the server, it will be seen in console. The only solution is for you to catch errors on server and deal with them there.

Comment: I use nodejs in back and my front is Angular5. In my back I add on every request status 200/401/500... And in my front I use the                         
err => {  if( err instanceof HttpErrorResponse ) {  if (err.status === 500) {           for catch the status error. But in Google Chrome console I have an error message about my request from nodejs. I don't want to show this message in my console browser Google chrome.   I have one idea use the console.clear() but it's not good idea I think.

Comment: @Valentin Valentyn Every response from the server will be seen in console. Errors will be like errors and good responses will be like code 200. Thats how console works. You can catch errors on server deal with them and then send code 200 while in response you can send description of error. That way there will be no errors in console but all responses would be code 200, while you will know there were error based on your response in body from server.